# Selenium execute javascript only if DOM completely loaded

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying get innerHeight, scrollHeight and scrollTop of a new page after user click the url,

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1]) # switch to newest window after user click some link
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))

documentElement = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollTop")
innerHeight = driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight")
pageHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

However, These script return wrong value because it executed before the new page is completely loaded. How can I get the correct values?

Comment: You can inspect the document's ready state using JavaScript. `driver.execute_script('return document.readyState')`

Answer (score 3):

You can inspect the document's ready state using JavaScript.

```
state = driver.execute_script('return document.readyState')
if state == 'complete':
    # the page is completely loaded
```

You can create your own custom expected condition that tests for this.

```
class document_complete(object):   
    def __call__(self, driver):
        script = 'return document.readyState'
        try:
            return driver.execute_script(script) == 'complete'
        except WebDriverException:
            return False
```

And use it like any other EC

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(document_complete())
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using driver.execute_script, you return your innerHeight, scrollHeight and scrollTop after `document.onload` or `window.onload`.

```
driver.execute_script(document.onload = function(){return document.documentElement.scrollTop})
```

`window.onload` is recommended.

Also you can try

`driver.execute_script(window.onload=document.documentElement.scrollTop)`

Comment: it return None after executed this script

Comment: Ah I see it, simply please try `window.onload=document.documentElement.scrollTop` inside execute script